# Gradle test task, how to set the Spring Boot environment for testing?

Tags: tomcat, gradle, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project setup using Gradle. I have an `application.yml` file that describes the settings to use for two environments named 'dev' and 'prod'.

I was able to set the default environment to 'dev' when the Gradle bootRun task is called, using the following code in `build.gradle`:

```
def profile = 'dev'
bootRun {
    args = ["--spring.profiles.active=" + profile]
}
```

But if I add the same code to the test task, it does not work:

```
def profile = 'dev'
test {
    args = ["--spring.profiles.active=" + profile]
    testLogging {
    showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Blade\javaworkspace\AutomationStatisticsPortal\build.gradle' line: 43

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'AutomationStatisticsPortal'.
> Could not set unknown property 'args' for task ':test' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.
```

Without that code the test task is picking up the configuration from 'prod' which is wrong.

I want bootRun to use 'dev' because that's how I bring up the application for manual testing. But I'm not sure how to make sure it uses 'dev' for the test task as well, and then make sure that Tomcat only uses 'prod'.

Can I assume that tomcat will pick up the 'prod' configurations as that seems to be the default behaviour if I don't override it?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
test {
  systemProperties['spring.profiles.active'] = 'dev'
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. The only way I can make it use the right property is by changing the yaml file. The propety has the same name for dev and prod. If I rename it for prod then it will pick up the dev one. But not if it has the same name. I need to keep the names the same.

Comment: I managed to fix it by changing the order of the yaml documents. I had 'dev' first then '---' then the 'prod' document. I just swapped them around and it seems to have fixed my issue. Really strange.